# Alternative vegan sources of Omega 3

Tags: nutrition, food, fats

What are vegan sources of Omega 3 that are not algae, seeds, or nuts?

Comment: HI there. Welcome to Vegetarianism SE. As a pointer, you might find some answers to your question [in this thread](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1609/where-do-vegans-get-their-omega-3s-not-ala).

Answer (score 8):

> What are vegan sources of Omega 3 that are not algae, seeds, or nuts?

It seems you're in luck - it should be easy to obtain from [these sources](https://www.webmd.com/diet/guide/your-omega-3-family-shopping-list#1):

> Vegetables, especially green leafy ones, are good sources of ALA, one
>   form of omega-3 fatty acids. Although ALA isn't as powerful as the
>   other omega-3 fatty acids, DHA and EPA, these vegetables also have
>   fiber and other nutrients, as well as omega-3s.
>
> - Brussels sprouts
> - Kale
> - Spinach
> - Broccoli
> - Cauliflower

Comment: Had no idea spinach and broccoli actually  had omega 3