# How to be healthy while ageing, on a vegan diet?

Tags: veganism, health, aging

What health recommendations can be given to **older people** that want to follow a vegan diet? Is there any particular concern?

**Related questions:**

- [Is it safe to raise babies and young children on a vegan diet?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/182/115)
- [How to be healthy during a vegan pregnancy?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/277/115)

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation for older people who follow a vegan diet is to practice a vegan diet high in protein to protect your muscles. Some vegan foods that are high in protein include beans, tofu, chickpeas, nuts, seeds and dark green vegetables. I recommend this high protein diet because as you age you want to ensure your muscles and bones are strong. In addition, incorporating physical activity every week will help keep your muscles strong.

You could also try out smoothies and shakes. Here is a [link to one of my favorite recipes](https://www.holonis.com/pbj-fit/o/skukejquf). Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Calcium-rich foods are more important than a high protein diet to protect bone density affected by aging.

Protein cannot be stored in the body; any protein over the daily requirement is expelled through urine using calcium as a binder. A high-protein diet can actually *decrease* available calcium to protect bones.

A diet rich in fresh fruits, vegetables, nuts and grains will provide adequate protein, vitamins, minerals, antioxidants. Particular attention to a concentration of calcium-rich foods like leafy greens, broccoli, okra, soy and almonds is a healthy route.

Soy products contain estrogen-like compounds which also help with aging bodies. Healthy diet and daily exercise like yoga and walking will also help keep aging bodies strong.