# Do commercial chicken's eggs contain B12?

Tags: vitamins-and-minerals, commercial-farming, b12, livestock-industry, eggs

If chickens are fed with only treated grain, where do they obtain vitamin B12 from? Are these eggs a good source of vitamin B12?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In nature, poultry get their B12 by pecking for insects and worms in the dirt. Since this behaviour is not possible on industrial farms, **B12 is added to animal feed**<sup>[1](http://baltimorepostexaminer.com/carnivores-need-vitamin-b12-supplements/2013/10/30)</sup>.

According to the USDA, one cooked egg (50g) contains 0.56µg of vitamin B12<sup>[2](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/118)</sup>. The recommended daily intake of B12 for people age 14 and older who aren't pregnant or breastfeeding is 2.4µg<sup>[3](http://www.mayoclinic.org/drugs-supplements/vitamin-b12/dosing/hrb-20060243)</sup>, though the FDA uses a higher RDI of 6µg for nutrition labeling<sup>[4](https://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/LabelingNutrition/ucm064928.htm)</sup>. At 9.3% of the FDA's RDI for B12, **eggs do not meet the definition of a "Good Source" of B12**, which requires 10-19% of RDI<sup>[5](https://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/GuidanceDocumentsRegulatoryInformation/LabelingNutrition/ucm064916.htm)</sup>.

When I personally consider what would be a "good source" of a particular nutrient, I am also interested in factors such as the foods other health effects, it's environmental impacts, and more. Wikipedia provides an overview of [health concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_as_food#Health_effects), and [farming conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_as_food#Living_conditions_of_birds) for eggs.