# Is Aloe a source for vitamin B12?

Tags: b12, lacto-vegetarianism

Can a vegetarian drink aloe juice to avoid B12 deficiency?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aloe has not been identified as a source of B12. I have heard that consuming aloe vera alongside sources of B12 improves absorption of B12 and vitamin C. [This article](https://www.newhope.com/supply-news-amp-analysis/new-human-study-finds-aloe-vera-enhances-bioavailability-vitamins-b12-and-c) summarises the findings of a study that found this to be the case.

The claims in the article should perhaps be viewed with scepticism since the study was supported by a trade organisation for aloe vera products. More importantly, the fact that aloe vera is only thought to *improve absorption* of B12, not to provide it, tells you the answer to your question - that aloe itself is not a source of B12, and consuming it will not be sufficient to meet anyone's need for B12.

Lacto-vegetarians may obtain some B12 from dairy products. [This question](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/923/what-are-the-best-sources-of-vitamin-b12-for-vegetarians?rq=1) may be helpful.