# How can I modify a fruitarian + dairy diet to provide sufficient vitamins, minerals and protein?

Tags: vitamins-and-minerals, protein, fruitarianism

I am a man with 37 Yrs and average body type with almost 80kg weigth with this amount protein needs (based of [this site](https://globalrph.com/medcalcs/protein-requirements-daily/)):

[image]

I am trying to follow a [fruitarian diet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruitarianism) with some modifications such as adding milk and some other vegetables (trying not to use plant roots).

I think this kind of diet may be lacking in certain nutrients, such as those listed [on this webpage about supplements for vegans](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/7-supplements-for-vegans#1).

> - Vitamin B12. Foods often touted to be rich in vitamin B12 include unwashed organic produce, mushrooms grown in B12-rich soils, nori, spirulina, chlorella, and nutritional yeast. ...
> - Vitamin D. ...
> - Long-chain omega-3s. ...
> - Iodine. ...
> - Iron. ...
> - Calcium. ...
> - Zinc.

So I would like to know if there are any supplements providing these, and also whether I would need to adjust anything to get sufficient protein following this diet.

Comment: Milk should provide most of it. An old school weight training programme named GOMAD needed (and still needs) its practitioners to drink a gallon (about 4 litres) of milk a day and do squats. While 4 litres may be difficult for most (including me), drinking about a litre or two of milk distributed throughout the day should meet most of the dietary requirements. **1. How much milk would you be able to drink in a day?** Again, we are unsure about your body's requirements as it varies on size of human and intensity of physical activities. **2. Could you mention how much protein you would need?**

Comment: Thanks @Severus_Snape, i coud drink milk almost two or tree time each time 1 liter, and about the second part ( protein ... ) i updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

**Milk**

According to [this page](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/buffalo-milk#comparison), the protein and calcium contents in cow and buffalo milk are as below:

```
Comparison between 244 ml of both types of milk

             Protein            Calcium
---------------------------------------------------
Cow          8                  21% of daily value
Buffalo      9                  32% of daily value
```

Now that, you will be able to drink 2-3 litres of milk per day, you will easily meet the protein and calcium requirements from milk alone.

According to [this site](http://www.milkfacts.info/Milk%20Composition/VitaminsMinerals.htm)

> Milk contains the water soluble vitamins thiamin (vitamin B1), riboflavin (vitamin B2), niacin (vitamin B3), pantothenic acid (vitamin B5), vitamin B6 (pyridoxine), vitamin B12 (cobalamin), vitamin C, and folate. Milk is a good source of thiamin, riboflavin and vitamin B12 . Milk contains small amounts of niacin, pantothenic acid, vitamin B6, vitamin C, and folate and is not considered a major source of these vitamins in the diet.
>
> Milk contains the fat soluble vitamins A, D, E, and K.
>
> Milk is a good source of calcium, magnesium, phosphorus, potassium, selenium, and zinc.

So, milk alone meets protein, calcium, and to some extent all vitamins and minerals. An alternate would be curd for days you don't want to drink milk.

**Lemons**

> Lemons are high in vitamin C, folate, potassium, flavonoids and compounds called limonins. [...] a quarter cup of lemon juice contains 31 percent of the recommended daily intake of vitamin C and 3 percent of folate and 2 percent of potassium.
>
> <sub>https://www.livescience.com/54282-lemon-nutrition.html</sub>

**Banana**

Fruits, like bananas (ripe and raw) are abundant in Potassium.

**Nuts**

Omega-3 fatty acids can be obtained from Chia seeds, walnuts, etc as highlighted in [this page](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/7-plant-sources-of-omega-3s). Chia seeds are cheap, but I wouldn't consider it tasty. I prefer walnuts or almonds or cashew nuts.

---

I wouldn't really buy any supplements as in the linked webpage of the question if I am drinking 2 litres of milk, lentils, lemon (or [*Indian gooseberry*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllanthus_emblica)), walnuts (or groundnuts) and any other fruits or vegetables on a daily basis.

There is a question here already, the answers of which have addressed specifically about patrticular nutrients. See this below:

[What are the main nutrient deficiency concerns for vegans?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/8/3874)

Please, don't buy any supplement without talking to your doctor. These are small things, but we really should be careful about.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer: I am not a medical professional.**

2 cups of lentils should be enough to cover your protein, 50% of your zinc requirements, and iron requirements for one day in addition to other food sources. Lentils contain 18 grams of protein and 8 milligrams of iron (80% of the male DRI) in each cup and are considered fruitarian since they are harvested without harming the plant. Lentils can be cooked like rice, [made into pasta](https://www.bing.com/aclick?ld=e8C7dTmOve8iwHb5qhi3LY4zVUCUxapT0WVXiO0TX4V4S5cSvKTvIWGWYGEt7RK2pGyY2tLuHn4kOhVtMKNbfhnQku-lfXOp2G7WMBZxdrsCJJfQQ7iJ27XcrlAlf6LPPx7tR73rWx5oKPao2gGjiXgO9YSQ19VmxgG6j_DhQ3u7A2EOQM4HYuOJdiqvswlMvADRa0LA&u=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&rlid=65bee2410b681f48c4e4bda8a0738ff1), and made into [tortilla-like flatbreads](https://plantbasedcookingshow.com/2020/05/03/vegan-lentil-flatbread/) that add variety to the diet. Protein can also be derived from other food sources.

Three cups of milk or equivalent amounts of dairy products will provide adequate calcium and vitamin D.

Zinc and vitamin B-12 can be obtained through synthetic supplements rather readily. Long-chain omega-3s can be obtained through algae-based supplements (but not algae oil used for cooking). However, these algae-based supplements are produced using means that result in the death of the algae plant. The only truly fruitarian source of omega-3 is flaxseed oil. [According to Harvard Health Publishing,](https://www.health.harvard.edu/heart-health/why-not-flaxseed-oil) 1 tablespoon of flaxseed oil contains 700 milligrams of omega-3; that's equivalent to slightly more than two 300 milligram fish oil capsules.

I would suggest eating lentils or other pulses in addition to grains (since you avoid tubers), fruits, oily fruits (such as olives and avocados), dairy products, and leafy greens.